# Spring custom JSF login page, always "Bad credentials"

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I'm trying to get a JSF login page to work with Spring security. I've looked around for numerous examples but none works. Every time I try to log in using the JSF page I get a "Bad credentials" warning in my server log.

Spring-Security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.css*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**/*.js*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-page="/Login.xhtml" default-target-url="/Secure.xhtml"
            authentication-failure-url="/Login.xhtml" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" password="admin"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <import resource="classpath:spring/security/Spring-Security.xml" />
</beans>
```

Login.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head></h:head>
<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="username" for="j_username"
            style="float:left" />
        <h:inputText id="j_username" style="float:left" />

        <h:outputLabel value="password" for="j_password"
            style="float:left; clear:both" />
        <h:inputSecret id="j_password" style="float:left" />

        <h:commandButton value="login"
            actionListener="#{loginBean.login}" style="float:left;clear:both" />
    </h:form>
    <h:messages style="float:left;clear:both" />
</body>
</html>
```

LoginBean

```
@Named
@Scope("request")
public class LoginBean
{
    public void login() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.dispatch("/j_spring_security_check");
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I use a non-JSF page as Login.xhtml it works flawlessly.

Page that does work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head></h:head>
<body>
    <form action="j_spring_security_check" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old problem. By default the FilterSecurityInterceptor will only execute once-per-request and doesn't do security re-checking unless there is change in the url but with JSP/JSF forwards the page is rendered as a response to the current request and the url in the browser contains the address of the previous page.

Before Spring Security 3.0 this was bypassed doing a GET request something like this:

```
String encodedURL = externalcontext.encodeResourceURL(externalcontext.getRequestContextPath() + "/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password);

    externalcontext.redirect(encodedURL);
```

But from Spring Security 3.0, by default it supports POST only.

So one way, probably the easiest to use is a simple HTML form. Otherwise you need to manually authenticate the request by getting the AuthenticationManager.

I guess the whole story originated from this [post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?84929-Can-t-get-IceFaces-login-form-to-work/page2) on Spring forums.

And the best working example can be found on the ICEFaces [wiki](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Spring+Security)

Here is the relevant LoginController class from the tutorial.zip

```
/**
 * This class handles all login attempts except html forms that directly
 * post to the /j_spring_security_check method.
 *
 * @author Ben Simpson
 */
@ManagedBean(name = "loginController")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    /**
     * This action logs the user in and returns to the secure area.
     *
     * @return String path to secure area
     */
    public String loginUsingSpringAuthenticationManager() {
        //get backing bean for simple redirect form
        LoginFormBackingBean loginFormBean =
                (LoginFormBackingBean) FacesUtils.getBackingBean("loginFormBean");
        //authentication manager located in  Spring config: /WEB-INF/authenticationContext-security.xml
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                (AuthenticationManager) getSpringBean("authenticationManager");
        //simple token holder
        Authentication authenticationRequestToken = createAuthenticationToken(loginFormBean);
        //authentication action
        try {
            Authentication authenticationResponseToken =
                authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequestToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken);
            //ok, test if authenticated, if yes reroute
            if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                //lookup authentication success url, or find redirect parameter from login bean
                return "/secure/examples";
            }
        } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage =
                new FacesMessage("Login Failed: please check your username/password and try again.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,facesMessage);
        } catch (LockedException lockedException) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage =
                new FacesMessage("Account Locked: please contact your administrator.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,facesMessage);
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage =
                new FacesMessage("Account Disabled: please contact your administrator.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,facesMessage);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Authentication createAuthenticationToken(LoginFormBackingBean loginFormBean) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginFormBean.getUserName(),
                        loginFormBean.getPassword()
                );
        return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
    }


    private Object getSpringBean(String name){
        WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(
                (ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext());
        return ctx.getBean(name);
    }
}
```

OPTION 3 : I haven't personally tried but even this should work:

By setting once-per-request attribute to false in your http element in applicationContext thus forcing security rechecking. But I don't recommend it.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="false">
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a life saver. With some adjustments and the `LoginController` code you supplied it worked. The `once-per-request="false"` solution didn't work on it's own though.

Comment: No problem! I am glad it met your requirements.

Comment: What is `loginformbacking` bean for?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question left me a little wanting.

So to get this working with a minimal amount of code in the controller (I wanted to avoid manually authenticating), I used a combination of a JSF (primefaces) form and a simple form.

I ended up with a view like this:

```
<h:form id="login-form" prependId="false">
    <p:focus for="userName" />
    <p:fieldset id="login-fs" legend="User Authentication">
        <h:panelGrid id="login-grid" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel for="userName" value="User Name" />
            <p:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginView.userName}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="userName" />

            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Password" />
            <p:inputText type="password" id="password" value="#{loginView.password}" required="true" />
            <p:message for="password" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <br />
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" icon="ui-icon-check" process="@form" update="login-grid" actionListener="#{loginView.login}" />
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>

<form id="hidden-form" action="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">
    <h:inputHidden id="j_username" />
    <h:inputHidden id="j_password" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mysubmit() {
        $('#j_username').val($('#userName').val());
        $('#j_password').val($('#password').val());

        $('#hidden-form').submit();
    }
</script>
```

And the backing bean could do the typical jsf lifecycle, after which it would send javascript back to transfer values from the successfully validated JSF form to the hidden one and submit the hidden form:

```
@ManagedBean
public class LoginView {
    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void login() {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("mysubmit()");
    }
}
```

You could do anything else you want on the server-side before the submit actually happens, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but I think you are specifying your backing bean incorrectly.

The correct JSF way to specify your backing bean scope is like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean
{
    public void login() throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.dispatch("/j_spring_security_check");
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using Spring container to manage the beans, instead of JSF's own, that's why he's using different annotations.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the info. Is it possible that Spring's container doesn't play nice with JSF view components?

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't make a difference. As @eljunior said, I'm using Spring to manage my beans.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `h:commandButton` to use an action method instead of an actionListener:

```
<h:commandButton value="login"
        action="#{loginBean.login}" style="float:left;clear:both" />
```

**See also:** [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: Didn't fix my problem. Nice tip though ;-)

Comment: Well... I don't know what else to try, then. Why don't you just leave the plain HTML form, inside the JSF page?

Comment: I'm looking for a 'pure' JSF solution. I may have to do other stuff when a user logs in. Pure JSF seems cleaner imho.

Comment: I don't know... JSF generates HTML and also allows you to write HTML in the facelets pages. In these times of JSF 2, I don't think there is a need to avoid writing HTML in our pages anymore. :)