# Spring Security redirect manually(by code,without config)

Tags: spring-security

I run a code for login like:

```
public String login(String username,String password){
    Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
                Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
return null;
                }
```

I do not use jsf and do not know how to redirect the page to requested secured page after successful login.

I was getting facesContext when using it but now i am not using.

How can redirect by code?

Answer (score 1):

Just return the view after checking for isAuthenticated(), like this:

```
 if (authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            //lookup authentication success url, or find redirect parameter from login bean
            return "/secure/examples";
 }
```

See also:

- [Spring custom JSF login page, always "Bad credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742283/spring-custom-jsf-login-page-always-bad-credentials/11746589#11746589)