# How to create a Bean to validate my login form using Spring Security 3.1.3 and JSF

Tags: jsf, authentication, spring-security

For the past days I've been trying like crazy to create a custom login page using spring security, but I did not find a working example nor figured it out by myself how to validate the form using spring, and believe me, I tried eveything, every example related I could possibly found on google.

The form loads ok, everythins is in place, all I need is to get Spring Security to authenticate the credentials against a database when I click the "Login" button.

Let me explain by breaking it into parts.

So, I have a login form:

```
<h:form>
 <p:panelGrid columns="2">

    <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Usuário:"/>
    <p:inputText id="j_username"
                 title="Preencha com o seu usuário (login)."
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="O campo usuário é obrigatório."
                 value="#{loginBean.usuario}"/>

     <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Senha:"/>
     <p:password id="j_password"
                 title="Preencha com a sua senha."
                 required="true"
                 requiredMessage="O campo senha é obrigatório."
                 value="#{loginBean.senha}"/>

      <p:inputText type="hidden"/>

      <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="customPanelgridTable">
       <p:outputLabel for="_spring_security_remember_me" value="Lembrar senha? "/>
         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="_spring_security_remember_me"
                                  value="#{loginBean.lembrar_me}"/>
      </p:panelGrid>

      <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Entrar"
                         actionListener="#{loginBean.doLogin}"/>
      </f:facet>
 </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

And I need the method "doLogin" to validate the credentials using Spring Security.

My LoginBean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String usuario, senha;
private boolean lembrar_me = false;

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

public boolean isLembrar_me() {
    return lembrar_me;
}

public void setLembrar_me(boolean lembrar_me) {
    this.lembrar_me = lembrar_me;
}

public void doLogin() {
  //Spring validation...
}

}
```

How can I do that?

applicationContext.xml

```
<http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
<http security="none" pattern="/static/**"/>
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
                  access-denied-page="/public/login.xhtml">

    <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/public/login.xhtml"
                authentication-failure-url="/public/login.xhtml?erro=true"
                default-target-url="/secure/secure.xhtml"/>

</http>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" 
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >

    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gde" />
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <user-service>
            <user name="teste" password="teste" authorities="ROLE_USER"/> 
        </user-service>

        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                           users-by-username-query="SELECT USUARIO as username, ISATIVO as enabled FROM usuario WHERE USUARIO=?"

                           authorities-by-username-query="SELECT USUARIO as username, AUTORIZACOES as authority FROM usuario_tipo_usuario WHERE USUARIO=?"
        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any help is much appreciated, I'm stuck with this for days!!!

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how-to-validate-a-login-inside-a-bean-using-spring-securit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481299/how-to-validate-a-login-inside-a-bean-using-spring-security/13497190#13497190) and possible duplicate of [spring-custom-jsf-login-page-always-bad-credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742283/spring-custom-jsf-login-page-always-bad-credentials/11746589#11746589)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the nifty ajax features of primefaces, you can not use the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter provided by spring security. Try invoking the [AuthenticationManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationManager.html) directly, then ([The Authentication Manager and the Namespace](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-manager) explains how you can obtain a reference to it).

Comment: You mean for example creating an Authentication object using the form data and try to authenticate it using the authentication manager I set on applicationContext.xml?
I once tried something like that but I couldn't obtain the reference to the manager.
I tried setting alias="authenticationManager" in the appcontext.xml, then obtain it using @Property(name="authenticationManaget") but it returned null and I tried and tried again ultill I gave up.

Comment: Yes. Injecting the authenticationManager should be no different than injecting any other spring bean. (May the typo in the Annotation be responsible? Does using the @Property annotation work for other spring beans? Incidentally, what package defines this annotation?)

Comment: Isn't it possible to do by redirecting via bean? I mean something like this: 
public void login () {
//send redirect to "/portal/j_spring_security_check?j_username=" + login + "&j_password=" + passwd";

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bean to validate a spring security login.

To customize the form login, the form-login element is the right place, and you can indeed specifiy a JSF page as `login-page`. However, that login page must provide the behaviour expected of a spring security login page. To understand that behavior, read the [reference documentation of the form-login element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-form-login) which lists the following optional parameters:

> **login-processing-url**
>
> Maps to the filterProcessesUrl property of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. The default value is "/j_spring_security_check".
>
> **password-parameter**
>
> The name of the request parameter which contains the password. Defaults to "j_password".
>
> **username-parameter**
>
> The name of the request parameter which contains the username. Defaults to "j_username".

That is, spring security expects the credentials to be passed as request parameters of an http post to a particular url. Your JSF form breaks that contract: It is posted to the wrong URL (because you use a h:form, which expects JSF to handle the form submit request). Try using a html `<form>` instead.

As for how to load user details from a database, the reference documentation covers this this in [Using other Authentication Providers](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-auth-providers).

Comment: First, thank you so much for you time.
See, the thing is, I can't use <form>.
I need <h:form> because if I use <form>, the <p:commandButton> (primefaces button) won't work.

It's like the Primefaces showcase for login: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

I need the button to work so I can access the doLogin and retrieve ajax parameters.

Would need something like this on my bean:

if (#spring security check ok) {
auth = true;
}
else { auth = false}
}
And as you can see, I would be able to use growl too.
You think isn't worth the trouble?

You think isn't worth the trouble??

Comment: You should really mention such constraints in your question. Will provide another answer ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I expected to be provided with a bean. Anyway, no excuse for that, you're right.
I've posted a workaround here (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?132463-a-workaround-for-custom-login-bean), in which I tried to create 2 forms (1 hidden) and use data from the dialog form to fill in the hidden form and submit it through javascript submit(), but I found it to be really nonprofessional and lazy.
I'm really tired and tempted to believe I should just leave it and use form...